# After I log in, Debian stops registering input

Tags: debian, keyboard, mouse

So I just installed Debian on my (other) computer, and I've run into an interesting problem: once I log in, the keyboard and mouse buttons don't work. I can move the mouse, but clicking does nothing, as do keyboard shortcuts. I installed from a 7.1.0 64x network CD, with /home, /, /usr, /var, etc. spread across multiple drives (I have a SSD and two HDD's). I know the mouse and keyboard work, as I've used them in Windows.

Comment: Can you ssh to the machine?

Comment: Nope. I just finished the install, and haven't enabled SSH yet.

Comment: Is it any different without X running?

Comment: Do you use a USB mouse and keyboard? Try PS/2 if possible.

Comment: As my answer (reinstall) is deleted, I wonder what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably won't like this answer, but I ended up skipping Debian and installing Window$ 7 instead for a multitude of reasons. This just happened to be the last straw.

That said, I have had numerous issues with network CD installs in the past, and a full installation disk may provide better results. Sorry to take your time!